Executing a command on only one of the attached LSP servers in Neovim
I'd like to run a ruff supported command on my buffer, to fix all possible auto-fixable issues with some piece of Python code.
I followed the setup instructions in nvim-lspconfig (note: I'm also using mason-lspconfig and mason, by extension).
I ended up with the following handler configuration:
...
['pyright'] = function()
    require('lspconfig')['pyright'].setup({
        capabilities = capabilities,
        on_attach = on_buffer_attach_common_actions,
        --- see keys at: https://microsoft.github.io/pyright/#/settings
        settings = {
            python = {
                pythonPath = get_python_path(),
            },
            pyright = {
                disableOrganizeImports = true, --- defer to ruff
            }
        },
    })
end,

['ruff'] = function()
    require('lspconfig')['ruff'].setup({
        capabilities = capabilities,
        --- see keys at: https://docs.astral.sh/ruff/editors/settings/
        settings = {
            configurationPreference = 'filesystemFirst',
        },
    })

    --- See: https://neovim.io/doc/user/lsp.html#lsp-config
    vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd('LspAttach', {
        callback = function(args)
            local client =
                vim.lsp.get_client_by_id(args.data.client_id)

            if client.name == 'ruff' then
                --- defers some capabilities on python LSP to pyright/basedpyright
                client.server_capabilities.hoverProvider = false

                on_buffer_attach_common_actions(client, args.buf)

                local function apply_autofix()
                    local params = {
                        --- command = 'ruff.applyOrganizeImports',
                        command = 'ruff.applyAutofix',
                        arguments = {
                            { uri = vim.uri_from_bufnr(args.buf), version = 0 },
                        },
                    }

                    local non_ruff_client_ids = {}
                    for _, cl in ipairs(vim.lsp.get_clients()) do
                        if cl.name ~= "ruff" then
                            table.insert(non_ruff_client_ids, cl.id)
                        end
                    end

                    --- Detach all clients that are not ruff so that the
                    --- execute_command does not reach them.
                    for _, id in ipairs(non_ruff_client_ids) do
                        vim.lsp.buf_detach_client(args.buf, id)
                    end

                    vim.lsp.buf.execute_command(params)

                    for _, id in ipairs(non_ruff_client_ids) do
                        vim.lsp.buf_attach_client(args.buf, id)
                    end
                end

                vim.api.nvim_create_user_command(
                    'RuffApplyAutofix',
                    apply_autofix,
                    { desc = 'Ruff: Apply auto-fix' }
                )

                --- activates autofix with a keymap
                vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>rf', function()
                    vim.cmd('RuffApplyAutofix')
                end, {
                    buffer = args.buf,
                    desc = 'Ruff: Apply auto-fix',
                })
            end
        end,
    })

end,
...

This works.  In short, as per nvim-lspconfig instructions, one must use the LspAttach trigger to create a callback that binds a new command (as with nvim_create_user_command).
The problem I have is within the local apply_autofix function.  As you can see, I'm using vim.lsp.buf.execute_command to call the ruff LSP server.  If I don't first detach all other LSP servers on the current buffer (pyright is also attached), then it looks like Neovim's execute_command will also try to send the same command to that server.  Of course, that command is not available on pyright, which causes a pesky error message to appear every time I invoke the command.
Is there a better way to implement the LspAttach function such that one does not have to detach and reattach servers?
